# ASP.NET CORE. Breakpoint in method only being hit once per browser session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

I do not have much experience in .Net Core.  I have a break point on the line  _db.AppVersions.Add(newAppVersion);.  It hits this breakpoint, has the right information and goes on to save the right information to the DB.  If I keep my browser open and try to add another new version.  It does not hit the breakpoint. I am at a loss.  Does anyone have an idea?

```
       [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddApplication(AddApplicationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var client = _db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(client => client.Title == viewModel.SelectedClient);
        if (client == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("SelectedClient", "Invalid Client");
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        var clientId = client.ClientId;

        var platform = _db.Platforms.FirstOrDefault(platform => platform.PlatformTitle == viewModel.SelectedPlatform);
        if (platform == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("SelectedPlatform", "Invalid Platform");
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        var platformId = platform.PlatformId;  

        var requirementId = _db.PlatformRequirements.FirstOrDefault(platformRequirement => platformRequirement.PlatformId == platformId).PlatformRequirementsId;

        var appVersionId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var clientAppVersionId = Guid.NewGuid();

        if (_db.ClientAppVersions.Where(clientAppVersion => clientAppVersion.ClientId == clientId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateReleased).Any() == false)
        {
            var clientRequiredVersionId = appVersionId;
        }
        else
        {
            var clientRequiredVersionId = _db.ClientAppVersions.Where(clientAppVersion => clientAppVersion.ClientId == clientId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateReleased).First();
        }

        var newAppVersion = new Models.AppVersions()
        {
            AppVersionId = appVersionId,
            PlatformId = platformId,
            PlatformRequirementsId = requirementId,
            DateReleased = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ReleaseNum = viewModel.ReleaseNumber,
            MajorNum = viewModel.MajorNumber,
            MinorNum = viewModel.MinorNumber,
            Description = viewModel.Description,
        };

        var newClientAppVersion = new Models.ClientAppVersions()
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientAppVersionId = clientAppVersionId,
            AppVersionId = appVersionId,
            DownloadUrl = viewModel.DownloadURL,
            Visibility = 1,
            Distribution = 1,
            DateReleased = DateTime.UtcNow,
            RequiredVersion = requirementId
        };

        _db.ClientAppVersions.Add(newClientAppVersion);
        _db.AppVersions.Add(newAppVersion);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("AddApplicationSuccess", "Home", new { showPopup = true });
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to put the breakpoint at the beginning of the method?
And step through the code line by line and see where it gets stuck.

Comment: Check your log what is the error message and share with us.

Comment: @JoelFleischman and Rena I will do both when I am done with current task and post the results.  Thanks so much for the replies.